# jQuery Replace DIV - Not working with 1.11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load content from a hidden div container into an active container.  This should be so simple.  The code I have works fine with old jQuery, but is broken with the latest version.  What am I missing here?

Here is my code in JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/poaw07w4/

```
$('.campuslink').live('click', function () {
var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/^.(\s+)?/, "");
var contentTobeLoaded = $("#faq_" + id).html();

$('#campusfaq').fadeOut(600,function(){
    $('#campusfaq').html(contentTobeLoaded).fadeIn(500, function () {
    });
});

e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`live` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. You can use the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to create a delegated event. (Don't forget the `e` parameter):

```
$(document).on('click', '.campuslink', function (e) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/poaw07w4/3/

Note: Binding the event on the document element corresponds to how `live` worked. If possible you should use an element closer to the element where the event occurs, to reduce the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .on('click') instead of .live('click')

https://jsfiddle.net/dotnetmensch/poaw07w4/1/

```
$('.campuslink').on('click', function () {
var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/^.(\s+)?/, "");
var contentTobeLoaded = $("#faq_" + id).html();

$('#campusfaq').fadeOut(600, function () {
    $('#campusfaq').html(contentTobeLoaded).fadeIn(500, function () {});
});

e.preventDefault();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The live() method has been deprecated since JQuery 1.7 ([more here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)). If you replace it with the on() method, it should work fine (note also that preventDefault() is moved):

```
$('.campuslink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/^.(\s+)?/, "");
    var contentTobeLoaded = $("#faq_" + id).html();

    $('#campusfaq').fadeOut(600,function(){
         $('#campusfaq').html(contentTobeLoaded).fadeIn(500, function () {
    });
});
```